# Binary Search Tree Insertion method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree, insertion

I'm working on data structures and I got stuck on one of the challenges. The objective is to insert array elements into a binary search tree based on their value i.e ( the root_node of the main tree is array[0], the left subtree's root_node is less than the parent node, and the right subtree's root_node is greater than the parent node). This is to be done recursively until all array elements are inserted into the BST.

I have implemented two classes:

1. That represents the node with attributes ( data, left, right):

```
class Node
  attr_reader :data
  attr_accessor :left, :right

  def initialize(data)
    @data = data
  end
end
```

2. The BST class to represent the binary search tree with the root value set to nil:

```
class BST
  attr_accessor :root

  def initialize
    @root = nil
  end

  def insert(node)
    insert_node(@root, node)
  end

  def pre_order(node = @root)
    return '' if node.nil?

    print "#{node.data} "
    pre_order(node.left)
    pre_order(node.right)
  end

  private

  def insert_node(node, element)
    if node.nil?
      node = element
    elsif node.data > element.data
      node.left = insert_node(node.left, element)
    else
      node.right = insert_node(node.right, element)
    end

    node
  end
end
```

- The `insert_node` is a private method for BST which does the actual work to insert a node to the tree. I separated it from `insert` because of the requirements for the expected solution which gets evaluated using RSpec.
- I then did a `pre_order` traversal to print each Node to the terminal window.

3. I have a `binary_search_tree` method which accepts an `array` as input and calls the `insert` method on each array element. It's main functionality is to convert an array to a binary tree and print out all the tree nodes in `pre_order` format.

```
def binary_search_tree(array)
  tree = BST.new
  array.each { |e| tree.insert(Node.new(e)) }
  tree.pre_order
end
```

If I run the `binary_search_tree` method with `[8, 3, 10, 1, 6, 14, 4, 7, 13]` as an argument, I expect to get the nodes printed out in the format `# => "8 3 1 6 4 7 10 14 13"` but nothing is happening and I don't know where I might have gone wrong. I have been stuck on this challenge for hours today, if anyone could assist that will mean a lot. Thanks : )

sample input:

`puts binary_search_tree([8, 3, 10, 1, 6, 14, 4, 7, 13])`

expected output:

`8 3 1 6 4 7 10 14 13`

got:

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I finally found a way around the challenge. I'm just gonna demonstrate how I did it for future reference:

So, instead of using two separate methods `insert` and `insert_helper` node, I decided to get rid of the redundant code and came up with one method to solve the challenge. Here's the BST class structure:

```
class BST
  attr_accessor :root

  def initialize
    @root = nil
  end

  def insert(node, head = @root)
    return @root = node if @root.nil?

    return node if head.nil?

    if node.data < head.data
      head.left = insert(node, head.left)
    elsif node.data > head.data
      head.right = insert(node, head.right)
    end

    head
  end

  def pre_order(node = @root)
    return '' if node.nil?

    result = ''
    result += "#{node.data} "
    result += pre_order(node.left)
    result += pre_order(node.right)
  end
end
```

The `insert` method now accepts two parameters `node` and ( `head` which is an optional parameter ), to allow us to perform recursive operations on the subtree nodes and yield the desired result.

`pre_order` prints each node's data, this is done in the recursive approach so each node in the Binary Search Tree gets printed out in pre_order format.

Now if you call the BST pre_order method for example:

```
def binary_search_tree(array)
  tree = BST.new
  array.each { |e| tree.insert(Node.new(e)) }
  tree.pre_order
end

puts binary_search_tree([8, 3, 10, 1, 6, 14, 4, 7, 13])
```

you get the result `8 3 1 6 4 7 10 14 13`. By altering the `pre_order` method, you can print the tree nodes in `post_order`, `inorder`, e.t.c.

I hope this will be useful for the others. Happy coding!!

Comment: You are a hero my G.

Answer (score 0):

```
return '' if node.nil?
```

This is the stop condition of the recursive `pre_order` and it's what you return from `binary_search_tree`. You don't seem to have anything that would format your tree in your desired shape, `"8 3 1 6 4 7 10 14 13"`. So add that logic and call it at the end of `binary_search_tree` method.

Comment: I haven't read the insertion code too closely and I'm assuming it's alright. Even if it isn't, it's irrelevant to the output mismatch problem we're having here.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the response @Sergio Tulentsev. The problem was actually coming from the insert_node method, it always returned nil for the main BST `root` attribute i.e `tree.root` or if you run the code in inspect mode you would see that no nodes were created on calling the `insert` method, hence the nil value on the terminal.